# Selenium Chrone WebDriver object hangs in Docker on creation

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

Trying to initialize a Chrone WebDriver object inside a Docker container and then perform a `get()` method with a URL.

I have access to the web from docker (can ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) and selenium is of latest version (4.16).

What happens, however, is that the moment `webdriver.Chrome()` gets called, it hangs. Simply hangs, infinitely, without any exceptions and errors.

Does anybody know what causes it and how to get past this problem?

Code I am trying to use below:

```py
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.options as selenium_options
from selenium import webdriver

opts = selenium_options.Options()
opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = opts) # this hangs indifintely
```

EDIT:
If I Interrupt the program at the step where the program hangs, the output of Python is the following:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 339, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 398, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 398, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 420, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1349, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
```